# Difference between ANYFORMAT and ANYFORMAT_RTP

Tags: java, streaming, rtp, formats

I want to know what's the difference in use between 2 formats, eg JPEG and JPEG_RTP. when do I choose the format ended in "_RTP"?

Thank's for help.
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTP packet format is optimized for real-time video streams where codec parameters change rarely from frame to frame. (compare to M-JPEG over HTTP)

See [RFC 2435](http://www.faqs.org/rfc/rfc2435.txt)